# How to rename project in RubyMine

Tags: ide, rename, configuration-files, rubymine

I'm running **Rubymine 5.4.x on Windows 7** (but that shouldn't really matter for this question) and I have managed to delete projects and seemingly rename them before, but I am stuck this time.

#### *In the past, this is what I've done:*

1. rename all instances of your old project name in all the files in the `.idea` folder in your project directory.
2. rename all instances of your old project name in all the files in the RubyMine config folder and subfolders (on windows, for RM 5.x - `%USERPROFILE%\.RubyMine50\config`)
3. rename all instances of your old project name in all the files in the RubyMine system folder and subfolders (on windows, for RM 5.x - `%USERPROFILE%\.RubyMine50\config`)
4. rename all FILES that contain your old project name to the new project name, a few examples - rename:

   - your actual project directory which would probably have the same name as the project to the new project name
   - the `.idea/<your_project_name>.iml` file

#### *In Summary:*

- By deleting or modifying these files/folders I have managed to delete or rename the projects that appear in my "project list" in that startup screen/Create Project/Open Project Modal for RubyMine, and in the ReOpen Projects menu.
- However, this time around I can't get the *name* of this particular project rename... that is it appears with the correct path in these lists, but the incorrect name.
- Furthermore, the incorrect name appears in my Project ToolWindow once the IDE is launch, although directly to the right of it in parenthesis is the correct path.

Any thoughts?  tia

Answer (score 31, accepted):

To rename a project edit `.idea/.name` file manually.

There is a [feature request to add Rename Project action to a File menu](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-10168), please vote.

Answer (score 8):

Updated answer done on RubyMine 6.3.3 when I wanted to rename the project directory:

1. Close RubyMine
2. Rename project directory to desired name
3. Delete the .idea folder
4. Reopen renamed project directory in RubyMine

I found this to be easier than combining the steps listed on the question and the accepted answer

Comment: You will lose all your project-settings when doing that, so I would prefer the answer of CrazyCoder.

Answer (score 2):

OK... I just figured it out... IN ADDITION to everything above... you need to rename the `.name` file (it's just one line with the name of your project) in the `.idea` directory in the root directory of your project

Comment: I just noticed @CrazyCoder's answer... he beat me to it... so, I'm going to award him with the answer acceptance

Answer (score 2):

In addition to modifying the `.idea/.name` file, there is also a `.idea/<project name>.iml` file. Open this, do a find/replace with `<project name>` and `<new project name>`, then rename this file as well.

Quit RubyMine, and reopen it. This will update everything. In your source control you'll notice a lot of other files which automatically got updated as well.

Comment: You also need to modify .idea/.module.

Answer (score 2):

The `.name` does no longer exist in my version of RubyMine (2019.3)

The `File|Rename project..` will automatically pick up the folder name change (if you changed it outside of RubyMine when it was closed)

Additionally, I had to rename the `<project name>.mlt` file in the `.idea` folder and change the references to it in `idea/modules.xml` (search and replace old project name to new project name)

```
<module fileurl="file://$PROJECT_DIR$/.idea/<PROJECT NAME>.iml" filepath="$PROJECT_DIR$/.idea/<PROJECT NAME>.iml" />
```